# Update rule of the mean shift filter $p(x) = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i = 1}^NK\Big(\frac{|x - x_i|^2}{h}\Big)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, optimization

Mean shift is a procedure to find the local maxima (the modes) of a probability density function from samples.

The first step is to assume that the probability density function can be approximated by its kernel density estimate
$$
p(x) = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i = 1}^NK\left(\frac{|x - x_i|^2}{h}\right)
$$
where $K(|x|^2)$ is a kernel that integrates to 1 in $x$ and $h$ is a bandwidth parameter.

A necessary condition to determine the maxima of a function is that the first order derivatives must be zero. By taking the first order derivative in $x$ we obtain
$$
\nabla p(x) = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i = 1}^N 2 \cdot \frac{x - x_i}{h} \cdot K'\left(\frac{|x - x_i|^2}{h}\right)
\tag{1}
$$
Next we rearrange the equation above to obtain the following iterative update
$$
x^{t+1} = \frac{\sum_{i = 1}^N x_i \cdot K'\left(\frac{|x^t - x_i|^2}{h}\right)}{\sum_{i = 1}^NK'\left(\frac{|x^t - x_i|^2}{h}\right)}
\tag{2}
$$

**My question**:

How do you justify the step from (1) to (2)?

Sources:

- [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_shift#cite_note-Fukunaga-3)
- [Queen’s University, Kingston, ON](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Ealiyari/papers/PRL2.pdf)

Comment: If its a maxima, the gradient must be $0$. If the iterates in (2) converge, then the limit point will satisfy this condition. (This is of course, not enough - one has to argue that the iterations defined by (2) will converge, which seems to be the subect of the paper that you've linked to, and that the limit is not some stationary point other than a maxima)

Comment: many thanks for your comment @stochasticboy321. I'm aware of the fact that the gradient must be zero at an extermum. But what I want to know if how you get from (1) to (2) step by step?

Comment: Equate the expression in $(1)$ to $0$. It should be straightforward to rearrange the equation into a form that mimics (2), i.e., a relation $x = f(x)$ where $f$ is the expression in the RHS of (2). The idea is only that when you are trying to find a solution that satisfies a condition like $x = f(x)$ then it's a useful thing to interate in the form $x_{t+1} = f(x_t)$. This is standard - the intuition is that one is looking for a fixed point of $f$, and when things are 'nice', then iterates will converge to a fixed point.

Comment: Still interested in the answer?

Comment: @Make42 it s been a while but why not?